# How to turn a photograph into a line drawing or sketch

Tags: photo-editing, illustration, line-art

How can I edit a photo so it ends up looking likje a sketch? Example:

[image: http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/430/509/f2c.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention any particular software, but if you want to do this manually it is a similar process in Photoshop, Illustrator, Gimp or Inkscape:

- Open or paste your image in a new document
- Lower the opacity of this first background layer so you can work on top of it. You can also convert this layer to black & white so it's easier to tell the difference in shading.
- Create a new layer above it
- Using brushes or vector shapes, re-draw the lines in the new layer following the darker areas.

Answer (score 2):

Open it as a background in Artrage and trace away.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a pile of different filters...find edges, posterization, adjust levels. But typically it's best/easiest to do just what Michael suggests...trace it.